# Oracle 11g and many listeners

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I'm currently learning database administration on Oracle 11g product and I have some problems :

1) When shared served is activated, we necessarily need two listener I'm right ? One for client's connection to the dispatcher and another for admin task like startup, ... ? (It's not possible to start a server when connected to shared server, I'm right ?)

2) On the client side, how can I indicate wich listener he must use ? I understand it's with de tnsname.ora file, but how can I set up It on the client station ?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as the first point, I am not sure. But for the second one..You have to install the oracle client(ODP.Net for .Net) and in that say path C:\app\Home\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin, the tnsnames.ora should be same as your server..

Comment: Thank you, but is there a tools or software to deploy it automaticaly and avoid outdated tnsname.ora file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must added (SERVER=DEDICATED) to your tnsnames record 
and you can run administrative task in your database

BASE1 = 
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *host*)(PORT = *port*))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = *SERVICE_NAME*)
      (SERVER=DEDICATED)
    )
    )

(SERVER=SHARED) - for shared connections;

Answer (score 1):

You can still have one listener. What kind of connection (shared vs dedicated) depends on how tns alias is defined. So just define separate aliases in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers.
I thought (wrongly) that once the database is configured in shared server, you can't connect to it in dedicated whitout special configuration on server side and that one listener can't accept the two connection type.
It's clear, thank you very much.